# Download large data directly from url to google cloud storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to download a large dataset from URL "https" directly to google cloud storage(Bucket).

I have used gsutil stream command. via google cloud shell

> curl -L https://../../..velodyne.zip | gsutil cp - gs://###/##/velodyne.zip

the result is

> We've detected excessive egress network traffic in your Google Cloud Shell session. Discontinue or decrease this traffic or your session will be terminated.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749589/google-cloud-storage-download-file-from-web)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're downloading to your local environment (the cloud shell) with `curl` and then sending to GCS.

The way to do this is to use the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/).

There is one option of giving the transfer service a [URL list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list), and the service itself will download all the data to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) in your local machine
2. Then run the command from there

It will download the file from your local machine then use that as input to your gsutil command. You won't be able to do it using Cloud Shell, you would probably hit a "No Space left on device" if your file is too large.

You also mentioned in comment to Jofre's post that you've tried the Storage Transfer Service but it failed. Please share the error so we can see how it failed then maybe we can help you.

Comment: I'm trying but low internet speed causes a long time. how can I get Storage Transfer Service error?

Comment: @christopher I am unable to use the Storage Transfer Service because I don't have the file sizes. I've installed SDK on my local machine following your link. How do I use sdk to run the .sh file?