# Resumable copying of a large file to GCS

Tags: curl, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am copying a large (19Gb) file from the internet to Google Cloud storage using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186589/) (I use GC shell https://cloud.google.com/shell). So far so good, but it is expected to take 11+ hours. I wonder if there is an alternative option for transferring such large files that includes the possibility of resuming the transfer if something happens.

```
    yulia_v@cloudshell:~$ curl -L https://archive.org/a_file.7z | gsutil cp - gs://a_bucket/a_file.7z
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Copying from <STDIN>...
  1 19.0G    1  237M    0     0   483k      0 11:28:22  0:08:23 11:19:59  351k/ [0 files][100.0 MiB/    0.0 B]      0.0 B/s
```

Comment: Maybe don't make the transfer pump all the data through your local machine and instead move the transfer closer to the bucket within GCP?

Comment: I am running it in the Google Cloud shell https://cloud.google.com/shell

Comment: `man curl` and read about `-C -` . I have seen this work on 60GB files from my pathetic home environment. Very happy I found it. Good luck.

Comment: 1) Do not pipe data (stream data) to `gsutil`. That will disable resumeable uploads. [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#resumable-transfers) 2) Read this article which has an example command. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas

Comment: @JohnHanley - I need to transfer this file from the internet to my GS bucket, bypassing my machine. Can I do it without "piping" data - I am not sure what this means. What's the line that I need to run?

Comment: @JohnHanley Also, I understand that gcloud's transfers are faster and can be resumable, but I cannot find and example where gcloud cp and curl are used in the same line - can it work?

Comment: `Piping` means to send data via a Unix pipe. That is the symbol `|`. You are piping the output from curl to gsutil. If you want advanced features of gsutil, then you cannot pipe data. If you must pipe data, then you cannot use advanced features.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think I can use local files: the shell is limited to 5Gb, and I have a 19Gb file. Running `gcloud storage cp gs://my_bucket/my_file.7z ./my_local_file.7z ` yelds `[Errno 28] No space left on device ERROR: Failed to download one or more component of sliced download.`
  Completed files 0/1 | 4.5GiB/19.1GiB

Comment: Then you cannot use Cloud Shell. Launch a Compute Engine instance. Always use the correct service/tool for the task.